# Partition switching migration from SQL Server to Azure SQL DB

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, partitioning

I need to migrate my SQL DWH partition switching logic to Azure SQL Database. Have anyone done this before and is there any complexity in doing the same. I dont find any references in Google for this migration.

Comment: Googling for `azure sql partitioning` or `azure sql partition switching` returns multiple results. There's no difference apart from being unable to specify the file group. One of the results is [Azure SQL Database Table Partitioning Example](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5407/azure-sql-database-table-partitioning-example/) Have you tried something? Did you encounter a problem?

Comment: Thanks..i have gone through this link..problem for us is we already have this logic in SQL Server and need to change the logic to Azure SQL Database..

Comment: You still haven't mentioned *any* problem. What logic? Why should it change in the first place? Did you try it and encountered a problem?

Comment: Please post your partition switching code. Then try it in Azure. Then you might actually have a question

Answer (score 1):

Partition maintenance code (adding/removing boundaries dynamically) is the same between SQL Server and Azure SQL Database. The only material difference is the filegroup specification, which needs to be `[PRIMARY]` in the case of Azure SQL Database.